# Help with custom shortcut - Fedora

Tags: fedora, keyboard-shortcuts, window-manager, xdotool, gnome-terminator

I am trying to set up a custom shortcut for terminator on Fedora 28. Connected a script to a custom shortcut. The shortcut should either start terminator, or based on whether it is on top or not, minimize it or bring it into focus and on top.

tried using xdotool

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if Terminator is running
if pgrep -x "terminator" > /dev/null; then
    # If it's running, toggle between on top and hidden
    if xdotool search --name "ADDME" windowactivate --sync
    then
        xdotool windowminimize $(xdotool search --name "ADDME")
    fi
else
    # If it's not running, start Terminator
    terminator
fi
```

However xdotool does not identify terminator or default Gnome terminal as a window, therefore can't find it (tried other methods than name and also list all windows with wmctrl -l). It just does not see terminal windows as windows. The code itself does not matter, currently just need to find out why/how else to do this.

Any advice?

Thanks